# How do I deal with different responses using Moshi?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

I get responses from websocket continiously (live), and all of them looks different, for example:
Response 1:

```
   {
        "event": "update",
        "status": "isOnline"
      }
```

Response 2:

```
{
    "event": "flight",
    "data": {
      "address": SomeAddress,
      "lng": 34.2,
      "lat": 78.6
    }
  }
```

I get these responses without stop in random order.

I also created separate data classes for every type of response.

For example, I want to get ONLY the lng and lat from the response  2 and show them in special TextViews  the emulator.
I ended up with polymorphism, it looks like that:

```
  val factory = PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Event::class.java, "type")
            .withSubtype(Event.UpdateStatus::class.java, "update")
            .withSubtype(Event.Flight::class.java, "flight")

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(factory)
            .build()

        val dest = moshi.adapter(Event::class.java).fromJson(message)
            .let {
             "..here, I assume, the responses should be filtered somehow.."
        }

        val destination : TextView = findViewById(R.id.destination_txt) as TextView
        runOnUiThread { destination.text = "${..*my lat, lng*..}" }
```

I feel that this is the correct way of doing it, but I'm a bit lost, what should I do after I got the destination? How do I filter responses?

Comment: Can't find anything specific but the keywords you might be looking for are "moshi polymorphism"

Comment: @cutiko hey thank you so much, just the way I'm already working on it, could you please check the updated code? I'm kinda lost how exactly I use this factory after that.